# Custom media type on client side

Tags: servicestack

I created a custom media type on service side based on the following link:
http://mono.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/vcard-format.htm

I have tried to look at examples for using a custom media type on the client side but could not find any...my client is a C# client and I would like to use this custom media type to post some data to the service..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want/need a custom media type client?

It's rare that sending JSON, XML, JSV, SOAP or using Prototype buffers doesn't fit, but when it doesn't the ServiceStack [generic clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) (JSON, XML, JSV, SOAP 1.1/1.2 and ProtoBuf) also all provide access to the `byte[]`, the raw `Stream` or the underlying `HttpWebResponse`. This can be useful for transferring custom media. [See here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) for more information and examples.

As `byte[]`:

```cs
byte[] vcard = client.Get<byte[]>("/vcard/1");
```

As `Stream`:

```cs
using (Stream responseStream = client.Get<Stream>("/vcard/1")) {
    var vcard = responseStream.ReadFully();
}
```

---

If you find the generic REST clients don't fit your needs, then you can create your own REST client based on the ServiceStack REST Client. You would need to implement `IRestClient` ([src](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IRestClient.cs)).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I trying to evaluate if ServiceStack meets my needs when compared to ASP.Net Web API. Since new formats seem to be coming up, was wondering how easy would it be to work with ServiceStack on both clients and service side.

Comment: @user3137645 You're welcome if it helped please upvote; and accept if it answers your question. I definitely find ServiceStack to be more extendible and flexible than ASP.NET Web Api. Did you read the [examples here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client)?

Comment: @Scott Hey Scott do you have a G+ profile? I'd like to invite you to a group.

Comment: @Scott great, just sent you an invite!

Comment: @user3137645 Are you still considering ServiceStack vs ASP.NET Web API, is there anything you are still unsure about? Did the answer help? Thanks

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for the reply. Iam still evaluating.